# Show that, $\forall A \in \sigma(F) , \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists B \in F_{\sigma}$ such that $\mu(B \text{ \ }A) < \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\Omega$ be a set and $F$ be a field of subsets of $\Omega$. Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $F$. Then show that, $\forall A \in \sigma(F) , \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists B \in F_{\sigma}$ such that $\mu(B \text{ \ }A) < \epsilon$

I want to do it for two cases : (1) $\mu$ is finite measure and (2) $\mu$ is not finite but $\sigma$-finite.

I believe once case (1) is done we could argue like the proof of Caratheodory Extension Theorem, but unable to give a proof.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What is the $F_\sigma$ in $\exists B\in F_\sigma$?

Comment: $F_{\sigma}$ is the collection of all countable unions of sets in $F$

Comment: Do you know the $\pi -\lambda$ theorem?